# Cannot compare two SFML Colors

Tags: c#, colors, sfml.net

I have to compare two colors in SFML.net. In C++ it's possible because there is defined `==` operator. In SFML.net Visual Studio won't let me compile the code. How to resolve that?
Error:
`1>E:\DB\Dropbox\Repozytoria\ARDSQL GUI\Sources\StatusBar.cs(91,17,91,70): error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SFML.Graphics.Color' and 'SFML.Graphics.Color'`

My code:

```
if (base.barRectangle.FillColor == Color.Green)
{
     ///Do something...
}
```

Comment: What is `Color.Green`?  `System.Drawing.Color`?

Comment: SFML.Graphics.Color. Both are from SFML.Graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing the individual components:

```
if (base.barRectangle.FillColor.r == Color.Green.r &&
    base.barRectangle.FillColor.g == Color.Green.g &&
    base.barRectangle.FillColor.b == Color.Green.b){
     ///Do something...
}
```

Or you could try writing a color comparison function of your own:

```
bool isEqualSFColors(SFML.Graphics.Color c1, SFML.Graphics.Color c2){
    if (c1.r == c2.r &&
        c1.g == c2.g &&
        c1.b == c2.b){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that I did not include alpha into the comparison (yourColor.a is how you would get it).

SFML is also open source, so you are free to add the operator overloading you desire:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

It's also possible that you are using an older version/binary that you found.  I haven't used SFML.net, but I'm sure if you grab a newer copy there may already be this feature built-in.